# dropdownlistfor not assigning selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at similar questions and cannot find an answer that helps me.  I am assigning the SelectListItem Selected property in my model method.  I watch the model as it comes into the View and it has the selected value.  But when it outputs in the view, I have just first value selected.

Model:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Index("ItemNumber", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
    public String imageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PDF Name")]
    public String PDFName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryModel Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCategories(int id = 0)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var x = db.Categories.ToList();
            foreach (var y in x)
            {
                //SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Value = y.ID.ToString(), Text = y.categoryName };
                SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Value = y.ID.ToString(), Text = y.categoryName };

                if (id > 0 && y.ID == id)
                {
                    sli.Selected = true;
                }
                list.Add(sli);
            }
            return list;
        }

    }

    public ProductModel()
    {
        active = true;
    }

}
```

Controller method assigning return value:

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(int? id)
    {
        ProductModel model = new ProductModel();

        if (id != null)
        {
            using (var db = new ProductContext())
            {
                if (id != 0)
                {
                    model = db.Products.Find(id);
                }
                if (Session["dropdownID"] != null && Session["dropdownID"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    int dropdownID = Int32.Parse(Session["dropdownID"].ToString());
                    model.CategoryList = ProductModel.getCategories(dropdownID);
                }
                else
                {
                    model.CategoryList = ProductModel.getCategories();
                }
            }
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
                <div class="col-md-16">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, Model.CategoryList, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What does the model look like?  How are you assigning the return value from getCategories to CategoryList?  And what is the value of CategoryID when you say only the first item is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the list item is being selected by the value returned by `model => model.CategoryID` and not the Selected property of the item itself.  So if CategoryID == 0 when the view is displayed, the first item in the list will be selected.  It's been my experience that the HTML helper ignores the Selected property of the SelectListItem.

Comment: that was the issue, I assigned CategoryID and it worked, thank you!